# How can I vectorize slow code in MATLAB to increase peformance?

Tags: matlab, performance, vectorization

How can I vectorize this code? At the moment it runs so slow. I'm really stuck and I've spent the last couple of hours trying to vectorize it, however I can't seem to get it to work correctly.

My naive program below works incredibly slowly. `N` should really be 10,000 but the program is struggling with `N = 100`. Any advice would be appreciated.

The code wants to iterate through the functions given `N` times for each value `w21`. It then plots the last 200 values for each value of `w21`. The code below does work as expected in terms of the plot but as mentioned is far to slow since for a good plot the values need to be in the thousands.

```
hold on
% Number of iterations
N = 100;
x = 1; 
y = 1;
z = 1;

for w21 = linspace(-12,-3,N)
    for i = 1:N-1
        y = y_iterate(x,z,w21);
        z = z_iterate(y);
        x = x_iterate(y);
        if i >= (N - 200)
            p = plot(w21,x,'.k','MarkerSize',3);  
        end
    end
end
```

Required functions:

```
function val = x_iterate(y)
    val = -3 + 8.*(1 ./ (1 + exp(-y))); 
end
```

```
function val = z_iterate(y)
    val = -7 + 8.*(1 ./ (1 + exp(-y)));
end
```

```
function val = y_iterate(x,z,w21)
    val = 4 + w21.*(1 ./ (1 + exp(-x))) + 6.*(1 ./ (1 + exp(-z)));
end
```

Comment: Besides the major `plot` cost shown in the answer below, you can further improve speed by not computing `exp(y)` twice. Notice how similar the computations for x and z are, it is trivial to derive the one from the other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe it's because of `plot`. Try:

```
[X,Y,Z] = deal( zeros(N,N-1) );
w21 = linspace(-12,-3,N);
for i = 1:N
    for j = 1:N-1
        y = y_iterate(x,z,w21(i));
        z = z_iterate(y);
        x = x_iterate(y);
        X(i,j) = x;
        Y(i,j) = y;
        Z(i,j) = z;
    end
end
nn = max(1,N-200);
plot(w21,X(nn:end,:),'.k')
```

Comment: Wow this worked a treat, What exactly was the problem regarding the plot function? The plot looks a little different though not sure if it's correct can you explain the steps for me?

Comment: you are calling `plot` N*N times (many). It's slow function. For plotting only last 200 curves `nn = max(1,N-200); plot(w21,X(:,nn:end))`

Comment: My bad. The second loop is needed though. The question is edited

Comment: Just curious the edit with the double loops has changed the values is that intentional?

Comment: Don't understand. Double loop should give correct results as you showed

Comment: The double loop and the single loop output different plots, i actually think the correct plot should be both of them put together, as this gives me a plot with the correct fixed points for the parameter 5. Double loop output [link](https://ibb.co/DLf8tsC) and single loop output is here [link](https://ibb.co/KD5VtNc).

Comment: Double loop gives the same answer as in your question. It's correct

Comment: why are the graphs different?

Comment: Looks the same for me: [LOOK](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uD0aGs6mQZiAQV6CjmcTHusAr3WSswH-/view?usp=sharing)